# Each time window resizes, the append method keeps adding to container

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to switch out my images in Bootstrap's carousel at the 768px breakpoint only for responsive purposes. So I decided to use the resize() method and append the smaller images to the .carousel-inner div when they reach equal to or less than to 768px or maintain large images if window is larger than 768. However, when ever I resize the window it keeps appending those images over and over again until I stop resizing. Only returns to normal when I refresh. Which this all makes sense that it the code executes every time the window gets resized. So I was wondering if there is a method out there that I should be trying instead? I kind want it to act like a media query... I have pasted my code below and you can check it out on my GitHub: https://ldgoncalves.github.io/ChamberStat/html/index.html

I'm using Laravel 5.3 for this as well.

```js
  $(window).on("resize load", function () {
            if ($(window).width()  <= 768) {

                var smallerImg = '<div class="item active"><img src="{{asset('images/slide4.png')}}" alt="First slide of a customer review"></div>' +
                        '<div class="item"><img src="{{asset('images/slide5.png')}}" alt="Second slide of a customer review"></div>' +
                        '<div class="item"><img src="{{asset('images/slide6.png')}}" alt="Third slide of a customer review"></div>'+
                        '<div class="item"><img src="{{asset('images/slide7.png')}}" alt="Fourth slide of a customer review"></div>'+
                        '<div class="item"><img src="{{asset('images/slide8.png')}}" alt="Fifth slide of a customer review"></div>'+
                        '<div class="item"><img src="{{asset('images/slide9.png')}}" alt="Sixth slide of a customer review"></div>';
                $('.carousel-inner').append(smallerImg);
            }
            else{
                var largerImg = '<div class="item active"><img src="{{asset('images/slide1.png')}}" alt="First slide of customer reviews"></div>' +
                        '<div class="item"><img src="{{asset('images/slide2.png')}}" alt="Second slide of customer reviews"></div>' +
                        '<div class="item"><img src="{{asset('images/slide3.png')}}" alt="Third slide of customer reviews"></div>';
                $('.carousel-inner').append(largerImg);
            }
        });
```

```html
<!-- Testimonials -->
        <section id="testimonials" class="row">
            <h1 class="col-xs-12 col-md-12">Testimonials</h1>
            <p class="col-xs-12 col-md-12">ChamberStat will get you organized, but don't take our word for it! See what
                our customers are saying.</p>
            <!-- bootstrap carousel -->
            <div class="clearfix hidden-sm-up"></div>

            <div id="testimonials-slide" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                <ol class="carousel-indicators col-lg-1">
                    <li data-target="#testimonials-slide" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                    <li data-target="#testimonials-slide" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                    <li data-target="#testimonials-slide" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                    <li data-target="#testimonials-slide" data-slide-to="3"></li>
                    <li data-target="#testimonials-slide" data-slide-to="4"></li>
                    <li data-target="#testimonials-slide" data-slide-to="5"></li>
                </ol>
                <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">

                </div>
                <a class="left carousel-control" href="#testimonials-slide" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                    <span class="icon-prev" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                </a>
                <a class="right carousel-control" href="#testimonials-slide" role="button" data-slide="next">
                    <span class="icon-next" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                </a>
            </div>
        </section>
```

Comment: I don't understand. What are expecting `resize` does? Your result is expected given this code.

Comment: You probably want to clear out carousel-inner before appending the same images. Also it may be beneficial to delay adding the images in until the user has stopped resizing. You can look at underscorejs's `throttle` method or roll your own with `setTimeout`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only want the content change to happen when the mode changes. And you probably want to `empty()` the list when changing content. Something like this:

```
$(window).on("resize load", function () {
  var largerImg = '...';
  var smallerImg = '...';
  var $carousel = $('.carousel-inner');
  var lastMode = $carousel.hasClass('small') ? 'small' : 'large';
  var newMode = $(window).width()  <= 768 ? 'small' : 'large';

  if (lastMode === newMode)
     return;

  if (newMode === 'small') {
      $carousel.addClass('small').empty().append(smallerImg);
  } else{
      $carousel.removeClass('small').empty().append(largerImg);
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This helped me greatly.

Answer (score 0):

Quick idea: You could store the last window size in a var. An only change the images, if `oldSize > breakpoint && newValue <= breakpoint`. And vice versa for the other "mediaQuery".